# How to change eclipse font sizes

Tags: fonts, eclipse

I'm trying to reduce the font sizes used in Eclipse. I've read several notes talking about how to do this, but none of them have made a difference.

Obviously, changing it in Eclipse preferences doesn't do it.

The common answers about using "Appearance->Fonts" doesn't work, because there is no "Fonts" tab.  I believe I saw one person say that the "Fonts" tab isn't supposed to be there anymore.

The next suggestion is to install MyUnity and change the font settings there.  That appeared to change the fonts used in other apps, like gnome-terminal and window headers, but it still has had no effect on Eclipse.

Comment: This solution worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805784/very-large-tabs-in-eclipse-panes-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Edit `e4_default_gtk.css`.

```
vim ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_*/css/e4_default_gtk.css
```

Add at the end:

```
* {
  font-size:8;
}
```

Save and start Eclipse.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Luna.

Comment: worked like a charm. All font sizes became smaller.

Comment: `vim ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_*/css/e4_default_gtk.css` isn't meant to be copy-pasted *literally* right? This opens a empty file for me.

Comment: You may need to edit a different file depending on your active theme, e.g. `css/e4-dark.css`.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the missing pieces of this.  The hard part is controlling the font size for the non-editor views, like the package explorer.  I discovered the following, which did the trick for me:

[Smaller font sizes for Eclipse on Linux](http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Oxygen release (and later), the CSS files have been refactored and the base `font-size` style should now be edited in `e4_basestyle.css`.

Answer (score 1):

go to menu `Window -> Preferences`, here go to `General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts`, this show configurations for perspectives, like java. In java option, select `The Java editor text font is used by Java editors.` and after `Edit ...` button, here you can change the font propieties.

Comment: When I said "Obviously, changing it in Eclipse preferences doesn't do it", that means I already tried that.

Comment: so what you need ? the answer changes the font, i test.

Comment: Ok, you're right, that changes the editor view. However, I appear to be unable to change the font size for the other views.

Comment: you want change the font of all IDE (menu, panel, etc) ?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Myunity on ubuntu12.04 64bit and it worked. If you change system font it affects the fonts of eclipse in menus and tabs.
For the text contents in text editors of eclipse you should change font settings from properties page of eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- Open `Preferences` under `window` menu:

[image]

- Go to `General` ► `Editors` ► `Text Editors`

[image]

- Select `Colors and Fonts` blue link under **Text Editors**

[image]

- Now you will see this window.

[image]

- Just pess <kbd>Edit</kbd> and resize your text font

[image]

---

#### You can also find it from `General` ► `Appearance`  ► `Colors and Fonts` then select `Text Font` under `Basic` option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Eclipse page [Tweaking SWT’s auto-scaling](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks):

> On GTK, the standard way to change to scaling for an individual application is to set GDK_DPI_SCALE environment variable before launching the application:

```bsh
$ GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.25 ./eclipse
```

**1.25** might be too large, so adjust it to your needs. You can even make the Eclipse font size smaller this way, say, 75% smaller than the default Interface font size; for example:

```bsh
$ GDK_DPI_SCALE=.75 ./eclipse
```