# Eclipse, for python project not jumping to function definition

Tags: python, eclipse, python3, python-2.7, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse, I created a Python project properly by installing all the plug-ins.

But now I'm unable to jump to respective module (source file) and method (function definition).

Please suggest me what I'm missing in Python Eclipse project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, for python project; we can jump to respective **module** (source file) and **method** (function definition).
For this, we need to add the packages into **PyDev – PYTHONPATH**.

**Project  ->  Properties  ->  PyDev – PYTHONPATH  -> Add source folder**
Browse the particular **package** (source folder) from Project

Once done, just click on the search keyword, which you want to search and press **F3**.
Else press Ctrl key and **click** on the search keyword.

**Note:** Restart the Eclipse, once.

[image: Add Python Source Code to PythonPath]

Answer (score 0):

I must say that you must try reinstalling Ubuntu through a terminal. My personal experience is, we must always configure our Python projects in a proper way.

For example ( for simplification I just choose a default interpreter):

[image: Create a new PyDev Project]

Comment: **Working sets** option always have such view?

Comment: Yes it has same view.

Comment: Eclipse fonts imho. Try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/514478/38988