# How do I change the font size / zoom level in the project/package explorer in Eclipse version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)?

Tags: 18.04, fonts, eclipse

I am using ubuntu 18.04 . I only want to change my **project explorer's** zoom level or its font size. Currently I think the project explorer is using my system font which I don't want to change.

I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/514478/1055334) but in my plugins/theme there is no css folder or css files??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I'm running Mac OS and Eclipse 4.15, this thread regarding the Eclipse theme CSS helped me change the project explorer font size:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731327/change-project-explorer-tree-view-font-size-in-eclipse-oxygen

The key part is to find the path to the theme css you're using. In my case, the path was `/Users/myuser/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_X.X.X.vXXXXXXXX-XXXX/css/dark` and the file I needed to change was `e4-dark_mac.css`. On an Ubuntu system the path is more likely to resemble `/home/myuser/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_X.X.X.vXXXXXXXX-XXXX/css/dark`.

I then added the following rule:

```
.MPart Tree {
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to locate the `.p2` folder in my `home` directory and added the code to my `e4_basestyle.css` and it worked.